# Javascript Callbacks to Output in Order

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

The output for these functions is called in the correct order as 2, 3, 1, but I like it to output as 1 first then 2, 3.

```
const firstFunction = () => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(1);
  }, 3000);
}

const secondFunction = () => {
  console.log(2);
}

const thirdFunction = () => {
  console.log(3);
}

firstFunction();
secondFunction();
thirdFunction();
```

I tried to use callbacks and it's not outputting 2, 3 after executing 1.

```
const firstFunction = () => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(1);
  }, 3000);
}

const secondFunction = (callback) => {
  console.log(2);
  callback();
}

const thirdFunction = (callback) => {
  console.log(3);
  callback();
}

firstFunction(function() {
  secondFunction(function() {
    thirdFunction();
  });
});
```

How do I achieve this by using callbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstFunction is the first one which should have callback. And, is there any reason you have setTimeout inside firstFunction?

```js
const firstFunction = (callback) => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(1);
    callback();
  }, 3000);
}

const secondFunction = () => {
  console.log(2);
}

const thirdFunction = () => {
  console.log(3);
}

firstFunction(function() {
  secondFunction();
  thirdFunction();
});
```